# Need Help Creating an inventory system using a List of ScriptableObjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

SOLVED

thank you for taking the time to view my question.

I am currently working on a project using Unity3D and have ran into a bit of difficulty whilst  creating the inventory system. Upon doing some research I have decided that it would be in my best interest to use a List of ScriptableObjects (Item) to create this inventory system due to the ease of management and the expand-ability of Lists.

Just as an example I have an Item titled "Skull." When the player points towards the skull my code prompts the user to press F to pick up the item which in turn should remove the item instance from the game-world and add an instance of that Item into the inventory.

The part that is causing me the most trouble is my InventoryEditor script which controls the RayCast feature I mentioned previously.

Here is the code in my InventoryEditor Script with the exception of Update and Start methods as they are working as intended

```
using UnityEngine;

public class InventoryEditor : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool isOpen = false;

    public TMPro.TMP_Text itemIDTM;

    public GameObject currentObject;
    public GameObject inventoryUI;

    new Inventory playerInventory;


    public void CurrentObject()
    {
        RaycastHit itemHit;
        Ray itemFinder = new Ray(this.transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward));

        if (Physics.Raycast(itemFinder, out itemHit))
        {
            if (itemHit.collider.tag == "Item")
            {
                // Rather than itemHit.collider.name I would prefer if it uses the Identifier of the
                        //Item ScriptableObject              V
                itemIDTM.text = "F - Pick up: " + itemHit.collider.name;

                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
                {
                    /*
                    I need to Add an Item When F is pressed
                    Something along the lines of:
                        playerInventory.AddItem(Item that is hit by RayCast);
                    */
                }
            }
            else
            {
                itemIDTM.text = "";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my ScriptableObject which has not been causing me any issues

```
    using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
    public string identifier;
    public GameObject model;
    public int value;
    public double weight;


    Item(string identifierStr)
    {
        this.identifier = identifierStr;
    }
}
```

Here is my Inventory Class

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : List<Item>
{
    public List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();

    // Default Constructor
    Inventory()
    {

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string itemListString = " ";

        for(int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; i++)
        {
            itemListString = itemListString += itemList[i].name;
        }

        return itemListString;
    }

    public void AddItem(Item itemToAdd)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            if (itemList[i] == null)
            {
                itemList[i] = itemToAdd;
            }
        }
    }

    // Remove Item Not Finished
    public void RemoveItem(Item itemToRemove)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (itemList[i] == itemToRemove)
            {
                itemList.Remove(itemToRemove);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only solution that I can think of is to use ScriptableObject.CreateInstance to populate my game-world with the items that I wish to add to the inventory but even then I am unsure how to both: reference those Item Instances in code and, use a RayCast to determine that an Item Instance is being hit. Is it possible to create instances of a ScriptableObject in unity without code or will I have to populate my world through code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated I have been struggling with this for quite some time now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as with most things there are many ways to skin a cat. There are some brilliant and complicated inventory systems in the asset store that you can use if you feel like this is taking too much time. If it were me settings up this structure i would make an interface called something like "IInteractable" for you items that you want to the player to have the ability to pick up.That interface would look something like this

```
public interface IInteractable
{
    //once a player has reference to this object they call this
    //method to get an item back (which is your scriptable object)
    Item GetItemInfo();
}
```

So in your OnCollision method instead of checking for a tag you could instead check against an interface like this.

```
IInteractable item = itemhit.collider.gameobject.GetComponent<IInteractable>();            
if (item != null)
{
//Then you have found an item that needs to be picked up.
  string name = item.GetItemInfo().identifier;

}
```

From here there are several ways you can go depending on what effects you want your inventory to have on your character. With some inventory you want items to have immediate effect while with others you want the effect only to be active while equipped.As far as spawning these items it would probably be easiest to just make prefabs with SO's attached and spawn those. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Good! let me know if you need anything else. Good luck.